# What does ::template do on a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I was looking through the `boost::python` source code and [found this snippet](https://github.com/boostorg/python/blob/832a1edd79905b8b8f3d5b573d4d8072e88fc938/include/boost/python/detail/pointee.hpp#L29):

```
template <class T>
struct pointee
    : pointee_impl<is_pointer<T>::value>::template apply<T>
{
};
```

I have never seen anything like this before. I am surprised this compiles for a few reasons:

1. There is no member named `::template` on `pointee_impl`.
2. `template` is a reserved keyword
3. `pointee` seems to inherit from two values separated by a space

Is there another use of the `template` keyword that I am not aware of? What's going on here?